# Masterpage in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013

I have customize the V4.master and override corev4.css and came up with fixed width design of my sharepoint 2010 portal. Now its about time to move on to SharePoint 2013 and its abit different then 2010.

Before gets my hard dirty with masterpages in 2013 I would like to know how different is v4 of 2010 then 2013 any masterpages and how long it will take me to do similar thing in 2013. Also guide how to go about it.